# tuist cache not taken into account when generating project file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcodebuild, tuist

I am trying the caching features of tuist (https://tuist.io) using one of the demos provided on Github, the app_with_spm_dependencies (https://github.com/tuist/tuist/tree/main/projects/tuist/fixtures/app_with_spm_dependencies). I was trying to see the power of caching dependencies using tuist. My approach was running the commands `tuist fetch` and I got here a warning about some watch target, but it shouldn't invalidate the iOS simulator targets, `tuist cache warm`, and finally `tuist generate`. I didn't see any changes in the build times. Checking the ~/.tuist/Cache/BuildCache shows an empty folder. The command `tuist cache print-hashes` outputs a list of hashes of the targets and external dependencies of this demo project, therefore I can assume some hashes were created. But where is the cache stored in this case? Why is the cache not being used on the tuist generated project file in Xcode 14?
I saw the compile steps for each dependency so I am sure everything is being built from scratch.

Comment: What tuist version are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest version 3.12.0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is all down to expectations. `tuist cache` is nothing more than what a clean build on the Xcode project would do: download dependencies into your Build folder and compile them to be used by your code. Each `clean`command erases the Build folder, which in turn results in an empty cache. So, it turns out that the caching feature, in practice, would be the same as keeping the Build folder intact.

Answer (score 0):

`tuist cache warm` pre-compiles all the modules (internal + external), but if you want to use those compiled frameworks you need to generate exact module that you want to work on.

For example if you are going to export an IPA, you just need to generate main application module where your app target reside. or if you want to work on particular thing on a submodule, you just need to generate that submodule.

Running tuist generate without passing proper module to it doesn't add much value.